# How can I create a user-generated page on my website?

Tags: php, url-rewriting

For example, say if a user wanted to 'add a place' to my database, how could I create a page almost instantly with that place's name in the domain e.g www.mydomain.com/placename?

I understand it might be a complex solution so if it is too complex to explain can you please push me into the right direction of what I should be researching.

Comment: what you're possibly looking for is mod_rewrite, so any new place generated can be accessed via www.mydomain.com/placename, which actually gets rewritten by your server to something like: www.mydomain.com/places.php?place=rome

Comment: Will that "place" be just one page, or will it be a store for various different files etc.?

Answer (score 2):

- Create functionality to create "pretty urls" in php. Read more about that here: http://www.roscripts.com/Pretty_URLs_-_a_guide_to_URL_rewriting-168.html
- Create parsing functionality for the urls, so that it recognizes "/placename" as the page "placename"
- Create a database structure for pages with the page id, title, content and the url slug, etc.
- Create functionality to fetch the right page from the database according to the matching url slug.
- Create functionality to render the retrieved informaton

If I understood you right that's one approach to what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

First of all try to understand mod rewrite. 
You could "mask: a GET url into a much nicer format.

Start here :  http://www.elated.com/articles/mod-rewrite-tutorial-for-absolute-beginners/

Then google on and get yourself familiar with all the possibilities.

After that make sure the GET variable is unique in your database, to be absolutely sure use a unique ID.

Example :

```
domain.com/PLACEID/PLACENAME/
```

mod_rewrite could then translate this to your php script into :

```
domain.com/place.php?VAR=PLACEID&VAR2=PLACENAME
```

Search the data from the user/place through the **PLACEID**  .

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using Apache. If so, create a rule using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) that forwards requests for `/place/placename` to `/place.php?name=placename`. Then write the place.php script, which will pull the user page from the database and display it in the appropriate fashion.

That's one way to do it - there are others.